# Issues with the float property (And others)

Tags: html, css

Okay, so I'm doing a project for my college and the goal is to create a website with at least 2 html pages and a css sheet. My website is basically a spoof grillhouse site, and the issue I'm having, is that I want my "Concept images" to be displayed on the bottom of the page, and the quotes from customers to be on the far right but above the pictures. As it stands, my site looks like this: http://puu.sh/pOV0U/8ecc14ddd8.jpg

With the css code

```
#Quotes {
    float: right;
}

#Concepts {
    float: bottom;
}
```

Also, as you can see from the image, that my text is clipping with each other even with seperate div tags, and I've been sorta fixing it by inserting breaks under the nav list and such.

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Specials</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us!</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>                  
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
<div id="Quotes">
      <p>Having second thoughts about coming out to see us? Check out these kickass reviews!</p>
</div>
```

Finally, my text-decoration command seems to not be working

```
li {
    float: left;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

The links still have underlines though. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to change the text decoration for "a", not for "li", as the former overrides the latter.

Comment: There is no such thing as `float: bottom;` you can read about it in:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/float   (awesome site for JS, HTML, CSS and more)

Comment: I simply want it to be above my pictures, but off to the left, my pictures are going to be at the bottom of the page because they're the last thing in my code for the page..